# Python input interfering with SimpleXMLRPCServer

Tags: python, simplexmlrpcserver

I have a server along these lines:

```
from SimpleXMLRPCServer import SimpleXMLRPCServer
def ack(msg):
    return input("Allow? ").lower() in ['y', 'yes']
server = SimpleXMLRPCServer(("localhost", 8080))
server.register_function(ack, "ack")
server.serve_forever()
```

And a client along these lines:

```
import xmlrpclib
proxy = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy("http://localhost:8080")

with open(myfile) as mfd:
    for line in mfd.readlines():
        if proxy.ack(line):
            print line
```

This results in a fault being sent to the client. The fault code & string are:

```
1
<type 'exceptions.NameError'>:name 'y' is not defined
```

My assumption is the consumption of `input` over on the server side is killing the POST XML-RPC goodness.

I'd prefer not to have to code up some method with [two clients and a server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29262766/client-server-role-reversal-with-simplexmlrpcserver-in-python)—I kind of like the simple 1:1 setup I have going.

Really, I'm open to any alternate (python) solution.

Comment: Aside: Thanks for including a complete, concise [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using [`input()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input) where you ought to use [`raw_input()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input). Try this:

```
return raw_input("Allow? ").lower() in ['y', 'yes']
```

Comment: You are correct, but it isn't clear to me from the python documents *why* you're correct---would you care to elaborate? Thanks! Is it due to the 'eval' part of `input()`?